# difficulty in getting remote ip address from socket in java/android

Tags: java, android

I have a server socket in my android app and the following lines (listening/waiting for a connection):

```
rclient = serverSocket.accept();
String stt=rclient.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
```

I get this :  `::1`

Can anyone kindly tell me whats my mistake here ?

I have also tried `getRemoteSocketAddress`, However, that also gives some crap output.`/::1/::0142342` ...

thanks.

Comment: It would help an awful lot if you told us the actual output you got.

Comment: That 'crap' is an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting correct outputs. It's not clear why you think they're "crap output". They are in fact the correct IP addresses. [`::1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Unicast_Addresses) is a valid IP address, it is the IPv6 address assigned to the loopback adapter.